# arduino teensy no true HI-Z available?

Tags: pins, teensy

I am using this https://github.com/watterott/SilentStepStick stepper driver to drive a stepper motor.
I am having trouble setting pins to HI-Z/floating to configure the stepper driver.

To set the driver to 16 micro steps and full interpolation, one has to set 2 configuration pins to HI-Z/floating [(datasheet, p.9)](http://www.trinamic.com/_scripts/download.php?file=_articles%2Fproducts%2Fintegrated-circuits%2Ftmc2100%2F_datasheet%2FTMC2100_datasheet.pdf).
The example code on github (TMC2100.ino) just doesn't touch the pins at all, this works fine for me.

However, if I only add the lines:

```cpp
pinMode(11, INPUT);  //connected to CFG1
pinMode(10, INPUT);  //connected to CFG2
```

which should set the pins to HI-Z/floating, the result is different.
The motor turns at the same speed, but makes more noise, I believe the driver is using the 16 step method with no interpolation. This corresponds to both pins being interpreted as high.

This makes me believe, that the Arduino uses a different code at startup than being used in `pinMode(x, INPUT)` to configure all pins. I am using a Teensy 3.1/3.2.

How can I solve the problem? Pins 11 and 10 are hard wired to the driver, as it replaced the well known A984.
Apart from the obvious "don't configure the pins then", I would like to know what's going on here.

Comment: Examine your circuit for possible pulling resistors.  Check the Teensy code details or look up and directly query the relevant raw kinetis gpio configuration registers.

Comment: If there were any pulling resistors, then it should not work when the pins are not configured in code.

Comment: Then check the implementing code for the function you are calling and raw register values, or move this to the PJRC support forum.

Comment: The Teensy has internal pull-up/pull-down resistors which can be enabled or disabled through software, see e.g. [p. 231 here](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K20P64M72SF1RM.pdf). You may want to check the "pull enable" (PE) bit in `PORTx_PCRn`.